# Design for a many-to-many database relationship - exactly one of which is 'special'?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have a many-to-many relationship between `User`s and `Event`s, using a table `UserEvent`. Exactly one user is the event host.

I can think of two ways to implement this:

1) `UserEvent` has a `host` boolean column that is true for the event host.

2) `Event` has a `host` column pointing to a single User.

The second option makes it more clear that there's exactly one host, but it could be implemented within the business logic with the first option (if event hosts is 1, do not allow another host). I also like the first option because a host column is really just a UserEvent relationship. Is there a way to implement a constraint so that only one `UserEvent` for a single `Event` has a `true` `host` column?

Comment: How about a EventHost table which maps each Event to its only Host ? That table will have the host id and event id only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do is the second one.

An Event has many users (M2M relationship) so you need a relationship table, but the Event to Host relationship is unique, so the place to map it should be the `Event` table.

In my mind the Event-Host relationship is different from the Event-Users one. But, of course, maybe in your case the host is just a user that for some trivial reason is flagged as host.

Of course you can decide to keep the Host information as a flag in the `EventHost` table, in that case you need a trigger to test if there is already a user flagged as host every time you insert or update a row in `EventHost`.

Some databases allow you could use a Check constraint to scan the table to find if there is already host flagged user, but most of them allows you to do checks only on the row you are inserting/updating.

Sort version:

Go for 2 or, if you want to go for 1, use a trigger.